# Autocomplete in rails not working as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, typeahead

I was trying to follow this tutorial

http://blog.ragnarson.com/2013/10/10/adding-search-and-autocomplete-to-a-rails-app-with-elasticsearch.html

Now this is what i did

```
      <div class="col-md-12" align="center" style="padding-top: 1%">
        <%= javascript_include_tag "//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typeahead.js/0.9.3/typeahead.min.js" %>
        <%= form_tag search_events_path, method: :get do %>
        <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder: "What are you looking for?", class: "srchFld typeahead", id: "search", autocomplete: "on" %>
        <%= submit_tag "Search", id: "submit", class: "srchBtn" %>
        <% end %>
      </div>
      <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        $(function () {
          return $('#search').typeahead({name: "search", remote: "/events/autocomplete?query=%QUERY"});
        });
      </script>
```

This is in my view

I have this in my routes file

```
resources :events, only: :index do
  collection do
    post :import
    get :autocomplete # <= add this line
  end
end
```

Now in the rails console it works fine, This is what i run and what it returns

```
2.2.3 :001 > Event.search("123", autocomplete: true).map(&:eventname)
  Event Search (69.5ms)  curl http://localhost:9200/events_development/_search?pretty -d '{"query":{"multi_match":{"fields":["eventname.autocomplete"],"query":"123","analyzer":"searchkick_autocomplete_search"}},"size":1000,"from":0,"fields":[]}'
```

This is what is in the

```
GET http://localhost:8000/events/autocomplete?query=123 404 (Not Found)
```

And this is what happens in the controller

```
Started GET "/events/autocomplete?query=123" for ::1 at 2016-02-24 18:25:57 +0000

ActionController::RoutingError (undefined method `autocomplete' for EventsController:Class):
  app/controllers/events_controller.rb:2:in `<class:EventsController>'
  app/controllers/events_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'


  Rendered vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.text.erb (0.8ms)
  Rendered vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.text.erb (20.8ms)
```

Controller:

def autocomplete
    render json: Event.search(params[:query], autocomplete: true, limit: 10).map(&:eventtitle)
end

Comment: Can you show the controller code for the `EventsController` class? Based on the error message it sounds like that's where the problem is, but I don't see the code here.

Comment: @Sean i was actually following the tutorial, And it didn't say to put anything inside the controller!

Comment: What about this part?

`# app/controllers/books_controller.rb`
    `class BooksController < ApplicationController`
      `def autocomplete`
        `render json: Book.search(params[:query], autocomplete: true, limit: 10).map(&:title)`
      `end`
    `end`

Comment: silly me i do have this!!! one second